# What is relation between Bane and Ra's al-Ghul?

Tags: dc, batman

Was Bane trained by Ra's al-Ghul in the same way Batman was?

Which comics will provide me with better details about this question?

Comment: @Jef - I disagree. To date, Bane is still one of the FEW villains who has been able to out-fight AND out-think the Batman.

Comment: Because he was designed to!

Comment: First appeared within a couple of months of doomsday. Duplicate. It was a cynical marketing move, attempt to match/better the 'death in the family' stunt. Weak, they were always going to bring Bruce Wayne back. He is a marketing vehicle.

Comment: @Jef personal opinions are personal. I don't like either of them, but that has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: @Jef: as opposed to the Joker, who’s a sombre and considered meditation on the nature of the id and the duality of man, and was conceived purely with artistic considerations in mind, with no hope of selling a few more comics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be aware that Ra's al-Ghul only trained Batman in the movie Batman Begins.  It didn't happen in the comics (unless the movie has since been serialized that I'm not aware of).

The relationship between Ra's and Bane in the comics is summarised at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bane_(comics)#Legacy).  Bane impresses Ra's and is chosen by him to be his daughter Talia's mate.  When Bane loses a fight to Batman, Ra's is disillusioned and disowns him.

The story is contained in the *Batman: Legacy* storyline.  A list of the issues involved is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Legacy), and is given as:

- Prequel: Bane of the Demon #1–4
- Prelude: Shadow of the Bat #53
- Prelude: Batman #533
- Part 1: Detective Comics #700
- Part 2: Catwoman #36
- Part 3: Robin #32
- Part 4: Shadow of the Bat #54
- Part 5: Batman #534
- Part 6: Detective Comics #701
- Part 7: Robin #33
- Epilogue: Detective Comics #702
- Epilogue: Batman: Bane (one-shot)

Comment: I read the wikipedia part before coming here. I was expecting something more from this forum that wouldn't be listed in on wikipedia. Nevertheless, I'll read the comics. Thanks.